# How to disable caching in Redux toolkit query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

For some context, I have two queries, `getAllPosts` and `getPost`. Now whenever `getPost` query is triggered, I update the query data of `getAllPosts` using`queryDataUpdate` method. But calling `getPost` creates a new cache entry in the store. How can I prevent this caching?
My only aim is to update `getAllPosts` cache.

Answer (score 3):

That is essentially the one core functionality of RTK-Query. It cannot be disabled.

---

Note: The other answers here seem to miss the point of the question. The question here is about preventing the result to be written to the Redux store. You can/should not get around that, as it is the RTK Query core functionality. (Source: I am the author of RTK Query)

The question is not about making a new request every time, which the other answers here are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, it is a core functionality but the cache created by `getOrder` is useless for me. I'm confused by the fact that I can update the queried data from another query but it will also store its data in cache.

Comment: Then it is there. You cannot deactivate that. 
And since you copy the objects directly over, they will also not use up any additional memory - they are just references to the same object.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

this's what worked for me,

you can disable this by appending cache busting query string to the url - cache busting should be provided as param to the query method and then concat to the url.

```
getAllQuestions: builder.query<ApiQuestionsResGetAll, ApiCacheBusting>({
      query: ({cacheBustingVal}) => ({
        url: '/questions',
        params: {
          cacheBusting: cacheBustingVal,
        },
      }),
    }),
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use 2nd argument as `false` in useLazyQuerySubscription or useLazyQuery

```
const [triggerGetPosts, { isLoading, error }] = useLazyGetPostsQuery();
 


const handleGetPosts = async (reqBody) => {

const { data: postsData, isLoading } = await triggerGetPosts(reqBody, false);

};
```

References: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#hook-types

1. useLazyQuery

Returns a tuple with a trigger function, the query result, and last promise info. Similar to useQuery, but with manual control over when the data fetching occurs. **Note: the trigger function takes a second argument of** `preferCacheValue?: boolean` **in the event you want to skip making a request if cached data already exists.**

2. useLazyQuerySubscription

Returns a tuple with a trigger function, and last promise info. Similar to useQuerySubscription, but with manual control over when the data fetching occurs. **Note: the trigger function takes a second argument of** `preferCacheValue?: boolean` **in the event you want to skip making a request if cached data already exists.**

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the caching using the refech() method as follows:

```
const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    refetch,
    isFetching,
} = getAllPosts();

useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
}, []);
```

Now above query will be executed every time DOM is rendered.